# Why NSRegularExpression says that there are two matches of ".*" in the "a" string?

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, macos

I'm very happy that Lion introduced `NSRegularExpression`, but I can't understand why the pattern `.*` matches two occurrences in a string like "a" (text can be longer).

I was using following code:

```
NSError *anError = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@".*"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&anError];
NSString *text = @"a";
NSUInteger counter = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:text
                                            options:0
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"counter = %u", counter]);
```

Output from the console is:

> 2011-07-27 22:03:27.689 Regex[1930:707] counter = **2**

Can anyone explain why that is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regular expression `.*` matches *zero or more* characters. Thus, it will match the empty string as well as `a` and as such there are two matches.

Answer (score 2):

Mildly surprised that it didn't match 3 times.  One for the "" before the "a", one for the "a" and one for the "" after the "a".

As has been noted, use a more precise pattern; including anchors (^ and/or $) might also change the behaviour.

No-one has asked, but why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: I don't know why there are two, not three matches. I've checked with regular expressions in Java and it gives exactly the same result as `NSregularExpression`. Actually I don't need this expression - I'm writing simple tool which highlights matches of given pattern in the given text - to test regular expressions in another project. And `.*` was one I put to the tool and the counter said that there were two matches what was a surprise for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

The [documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on NSRegularExpression say the following:

> Some regular expressions [...] can
>   successfully match a zero-length range, so the comparison of the
>   resulting range with {NSNotFound, 0} is the most reliable way to
>   determine whether there was a match or not.

I more reliable way to get just one match would be to change the expression to `.+`

Comment: Part of the documentation you cite doesn't cover this case. I got two NSRange structures first {0, 1} for the `a` character and {1, 0} for the zero-length match whereas NSNotFound is defined as `enum {
   NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax
};`